# What database technology to use for legacy application?

Tags: database, ado.net, odbc, oledb, legacy

I am looking for advice.  I know stackoverflow likes "answerable" questions, I hope this is.

I have a *large* legacy (Windows) application, using a proprietary (ISAM) database.  I wish to investigate moving it over to using a SQL database: primarily MS SQL Server, I wouldn't mind Oracle flexibility but that is only a "would be nice", and probably shouldn't influence the decision much.

The application is written in C/C++/MFC, *not* managed.  At this stage I am looking very much to "prototype" an initial solution attempt.  I would like this not to be too complex, it can be refined if the whole process looks like it's going somewhere.

The candidates I see are:

- ODBC
- OLEDB
- ADO.NET

of which I think I have learnt that nowadays I should prefer OLEDB over ODBC.  I know ADO.NET but not the others.  However, ADO.NET is going to require me to use .NET/CLR/managed code from the application, which it doesn't do at present.

Any advice for which way to go?  Prototyping speed/simplicity would be appreciated, though obviously if I know the final solution will require a different access method it might be silly to start with another one.  (I would appreciate not being advised to redesign/rewrite the whole application.)

Comment: Thank you for the 2 responses (so far).  It seems I have one vote for OLEDB ("more modern design") and one vote for ODBC ("fairly simple API") <sigh>....

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use ADO.NET unless you intend to switch everything to managed code (which sounds quite unlikely).

That leaves ODBC and OLEDB.

[ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odbc) is an open standard, but [OLEDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLEDB) is a more modern design.  Considering your program isn't likely going anywhere off Windows I would suggest OLEDB.

**Note:** The actual database you use shouldn't matter much in this decision.  All of the above have great support for SQL Server and Oracle (and to a more limited extent Sybase, DB2, UDB, etc).

Comment: Can someone explain why the -1?  Just a bias against OLEDB?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend ODBC as it has a fairly simple API and object model. OLEDB is more complicated and requires a steep learning curve.

If you were doing a complete re-write from scratch, I'd recommend ADO.NET, but for a legacy migration, you'll want to keep it simple.